# Bash scripting for MySQL in

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu

good day all,
please i am new to bash scripting and i am having some challenges with my bash script for connecting to a mysql server to reteive information. this is my script:

```
#! /bin/bash

MYSQL_USER="root"
MYSQL_PASSWORD="bibson13"
MYSQL_DATABASE="fredhosting"
MYSQL="/usr/bin/mysql –u$MYSQL_USER –p$MYSQL_PASSWORD -D$MYSQL_DATABASE"
$MYSQL -ss -e "select name,email,username,password from free_users where id_user=( select max(id_user) from free_users )"
```

but when i try to run it i keep getting this:

```
/usr/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.28, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2
Copyright (c) 2000, 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Usage: /usr/bin/mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
```

please i really don't know what am doing wrong. i would be most grateful if anyone could help me with some information on what to do, thank you.

Comment: When I copy/paste your `MYSQL=` line into my terminal, it gets garbled.  Can you ensure it doesn't have hidden non-printable characters messing it up?

Comment: Beyond that, your command looks correct.

Comment: and `echo $MYSQL` to inspect the contents of that variable after you have set it.

Comment: try `eval $MYSQL -ss ...`. If that works, then replace MYSQL with MYSQL_EXE and MYSQL_ARGS (or names you find useful). I don't have mysql available to test with, but if I did, this is what I would try first. Good luck.

Comment: Don't forget to accept a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you have some broken characters. Specifically, where you meant to type `-u` and `-p` (with hyphens), you instead have `–u` and `–p` (with en-dashes). This probably results from copying-and-pasting via a word-processor such as Microsoft Word (which is never a good idea). Once you change those en-dashes back to hyphens, you should be O.K.

Comment: thank you so much, you are right when i changed the characters it worked like a charm. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 invalid characters into your MYSQL variable (E2 80) before each "-" sign.
Try to cleanup the line.